# Is changing root reserve blocks effects the Hard disk or its a OS dependent operation?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, root, ext4

My question is in reference to this excellent answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493357/558724).

I need some more info,

If I change the Root Reserve Blocks (*RRB*) to any amount other than default in some version of Linux, will that be consistent if the HDD is moved to another Linux build in a different machine? even for virtualized operations?

Can anyone please indicate the directory if the *RRB* data is stored in any place on the hard drive?

*Due to my low reputation, I am unable to comment on the main question, apologies if any inconvenience is caused.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value is not stored in any file but on the [Ext4 filesystem's Super Block](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/globals.html#super-block):

> | Offset | Size | Name | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | [...] |  |  |  |
> | 0x8 | __le32 | s_r_blocks_count_lo | This number of blocks can only be allocated by the super-user. |
> | [...] |  |  |  |
> | 0x154 | __le32 | s_r_blocks_count_hi | High 32-bits of the reserved block count. |
> | [...] |  |  |  |

(note: there are also an uid and gid values to override this reservation, and they default to root / uid/gid 0 though they can also be changed to an other user or group).

So moving the disk moves along the filesystem with its superblock with this value which will be used by the other system mounting the filesystem too.

Comment: Thank you, for the detailed information and for the topic name it will help in further study. Most of us newcommers are not informed about the topic ( the specific term )so it's very hard to find the proper info. Thanks again.